# python load json data error

Tags: python, json

I want to load this JSON data in python :

JSON data:

```
{"status":"success","result":{"users":{"5543295":{"status":{"payment_verified":false,"identity_verified":false,"email_verified":true,"deposit_made":false,"phone_verified":false,"facebook_connected":false,"profile_complete":true},"avatar_large":"/img/unknown.png","avatar_cdn":"//cdn6.f-cdn.com/img/unknown.png","spam_profile":null,"search_languages":null,"corporate_users":null,"support_status":null,"last_name":null,"suspended":null,"primary_language":"en","timezone":{"country":"US","offset":-7.0,"id":105,"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles"},"membership_package":null,"qualifications":[{"description":"Foundation vWorker Member","level":null,"icon_url":"/img/insignia/vworker.png","icon_name":"vworker","score_percentage":null,"user_percentile":null,"type":null,"id":null,"name":null}],"id":5543295,"badges":null,"hourly_rate":null,"responsiveness":null,"first_name":null,"display_name":"vw693015vw","tagline":null,"account_balances":null,"public_name":"vw693015vw","role":"employer","location":{"administrative_area":null,"city":null,"country":{"highres_flag_url":"/img/flags/highres_png/unknown.png","code":null,"name":"","flag_url_cdn":"//cdn5.f-cdn.com/img/flags/png/unknown.png","highres_flag_url_cdn":"//cdn5.f-cdn.com/img/flags/highres_png/unknown.png","flag_url":"/img/flags/png/unknown.png"},"vicinity":null,"longitude":null,"full_address":null,"latitude":null},"closed":false,"email":null,"username":"vw693015vw","is_local":null,"endorsements":null,"jobs":[],"employer_reputation":{"user_id":5543295,"last3months":{"completion_rate":null,"all":null,"incomplete_reviews":null,"complete":null,"on_time":null,"on_budget":null,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":null,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"clarity_spec":0.0,"payment_prom":0.0,"work_for_again":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":null},"entire_history":{"completion_rate":null,"all":null,"incomplete_reviews":null,"complete":null,"on_time":null,"on_budget":null,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":null,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"clarity_spec":0.0,"payment_prom":0.0,"work_for_again":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":null},"earnings_score":0.0,"role":"employer","job_history":{"job_counts":[],"count_other":0},"last12months":{"completion_rate":null,"all":null,"incomplete_reviews":null,"complete":null,"on_time":null,"on_budget":null,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":null,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"clarity_spec":0.0,"payment_prom":0.0,"work_for_again":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":null},"project_stats":{"draft":0,"open":0,"complete":0,"pending":0,"work_in_progress":0}},"company":"","registration_date":1041968572,"is_active":null,"avatar_large_cdn":"//cdn6.f-cdn.com/img/unknown.png","profile_description":"","address":null,"limited_account":false,"portfolio_count":0,"preferred_freelancer":false,"true_location":null,"primary_currency":{"code":"USD","name":"US Dollar","country":"US","sign":"$","exchange_rate":1.0,"id":1},"mobile_tracking":null,"test_user":false,"chosen_role":"both","reputation":{"user_id":5543295,"last3months":{"completion_rate":0.0,"all":0,"incomplete_reviews":0,"complete":0,"on_time":0.0,"on_budget":0.0,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":0,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"expertise":0.0,"hire_again":0.0,"quality":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":0},"entire_history":{"completion_rate":0.0,"all":0,"incomplete_reviews":0,"complete":0,"on_time":0.0,"on_budget":0.0,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":0,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"expertise":0.0,"hire_again":0.0,"quality":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":0},"earnings_score":0.0,"role":"freelancer","job_history":{"job_counts":[],"count_other":0},"last12months":{"completion_rate":0.0,"all":0,"incomplete_reviews":0,"complete":0,"on_time":0.0,"on_budget":0.0,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":0,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"expertise":0.0,"hire_{"status":"success","result":{"users":{"5543296":{"status":{"payment_verified":false,"identity_verified":false,"email_verified":true,"deposit_made":false,"phone_verified":false,"facebook_connected":false,"profile_complete":true},"avatar_large":"/img/unknown.png","avatar_cdn":"//cdn6.f-cdn.com/img/unknown.png","spam_profile":null,"search_languages":null,"corporate_users":null,"support_status":null,"last_name":null,"suspended":null,"primary_language":"en","timezone":{"country":"IN","offset":5.5,"id":164,"timezone":"Asia/Calcutta"},"membership_package":null,"qualifications":[{"description":"Foundation vWorker Member","level":null,"icon_url":"/img/insignia/vworker.png","icon_name":"vworker","score_percentage":null,"user_percentile":null,"type":null,"id":null,"name":null}],"id":5543296,"badges":null,"hourly_rate":null,"responsiveness":null,"first_name":null,"display_name":"vw1619364vw","tagline":null,"account_balances":null,"public_name":"vw1619364vw","role":"employer","location":{"administrative_area":null,"city":null,"country":{"highres_flag_url":"/img/flags/highres_png/unknown.png","code":null,"name":"","flag_url_cdn":"//cdn5.f-cdn.com/img/flags/png/unknown.png","highres_flag_url_cdn":"//cdn5.f-cdn.com/img/flags/highres_png/unknown.png","flag_url":"/img/flags/png/unknown.png"},"vicinity":null,"longitude":null,"full_address":null,"latitude":null},"closed":false,"email":null,"username":"vw1619364vw","is_local":null,"endorsements":null,"jobs":[],"employer_reputation":{"user_id":5543296,"last3months":{"completion_rate":null,"all":null,"incomplete_reviews":null,"complete":null,"on_time":null,"on_budget":null,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":null,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"clarity_spec":0.0,"payment_prom":0.0,"work_for_again":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":null},"entire_history":{"completion_rate":null,"all":null,"incomplete_reviews":null,"complete":null,"on_time":null,"on_budget":null,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":null,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"clarity_spec":0.0,"payment_prom":0.0,"work_for_again":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":null},"earnings_score":0.0,"role":"employer","job_history":{"job_counts":[],"count_other":0},"last12months":{"completion_rate":null,"all":null,"incomplete_reviews":null,"complete":null,"on_time":null,"on_budget":null,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":null,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"clarity_spec":0.0,"payment_prom":0.0,"work_for_again":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":null},"project_stats":{"draft":0,"open":0,"complete":0,"pending":0,"work_in_progress":0}},"company":"","registration_date":1124680669,"is_active":null,"avatar_large_cdn":"//cdn6.f-cdn.com/img/unknown.png","profile_description":"","address":null,"limited_account":false,"portfolio_count":0,"preferred_freelancer":false,"true_location":null,"primary_currency":{"code":"USD","name":"US Dollar","country":"US","sign":"$","exchange_rate":1.0,"id":1},"mobile_tracking":null,"test_user":false,"chosen_role":"both","reputation":{"user_id":5543296,"last3months":{"completion_rate":0.0,"all":0,"incomplete_reviews":0,"complete":0,"on_time":0.0,"on_budget":0.0,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":0,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"expertise":0.0,"hire_again":0.0,"quality":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":0},"entire_history":{"completion_rate":0.0,"all":0,"incomplete_reviews":0,"complete":0,"on_time":0.0,"on_budget":0.0,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":0,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"expertise":0.0,"hire_again":0.0,"quality":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":0},"earnings_score":0.0,"role":"freelancer","job_history":{"job_counts":[],"count_other":0},"last12months":{"completion_rate":0.0,"all":0,"incomplete_reviews":0,"complete":0,"on_time":0.0,"on_budget":0.0,"positive":0.0,"overall":0.0,"reviews":0,"category_ratings":{"communication":0.0,"expertise":0.0,"hire_agaiagain":0.0,"quality":0.0,"professionalism":0.0},"earnings":null,"rehire_rate":null,"incomplete":0},"project_stats":null},"avatar":"/img/unknown.png","cover_image":{"current_image":{"url":"//cdn2.f-cdn.com/static/img/profiles/cover-product.jpg","width":1920,"height":550,"id":null,"description":""},"past_images":null},"corporate":null,"force_verify":null}}},"request_id":"2520481ca4d6b8130bdc20f6114d8037"}
```

My Python code :

```
import json
json_data = open('test.txt', 'r').read()
data = json.loads(json_data)
```

I'm sure JSON data is valid, because is result of one website, I need to load this in python and get username value.

Actual error :

```
MacBook-Pro-di-admin:freelancer11 admin$ python load.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = json.loads(json_data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting : delimiter: line 1 column 4099 (char 4098)
```

Answer (score 2):

So if you head over to your favorite JSON validator, like [JSONlint](https://jsonlint.com/), you will see the JSON is not valid, and that is precisely what the error in python means.

Comment: how i can fix ? what i need to replace in actual json code ?

Comment: If you check out the validator, you will see that the JSON is a big mess.  The best way to fix it is to fix the program creating the JSON text file.